# R: How to group questionnaire items?

Tags: r

I am pretty much a beginner in R. I have been searching the web these last few days and I can't believe I haven't found an answer to my (seemingly simple) problem. Please forgive me, I would love to learn how to do this.

I have conducted a questionnaire on gforms where participants rated items from 1 to 10. After transposing, I have rows with the individual items.

What I want to do is to group the individual rows/items by category (6 in total) in order to compare the scores per category. So, let me say, rows 1-3 are category 'A', rows 4-6 category 'B', etc. But: how can I do this with a dataset like this?

```
                          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
new.vs.ancient               8    1    4    3    1    8    1    1    1     2     1     1     8
shrink.vs.grow               2    1    1    7    1    7    1    1    1     1     1     1     4
bad.vs.great                 3    1    2    2    1    8    1    1    1     2     1     1     4
presence.vs.absence          9    1    1    1    1    8    1    1    1     1     1     1     2
smart.vs.dumb                1    1    3    1    1    8    1    1    1     1     1     2     3
spend.vs.save                2    1    2    1    1    8    1    1    1     2     1     1     1
easy.vs.difficult            1    1    3    1    1    6    1    1    1     1     1     1     1
tiny.vs.huge                 1    1    1    1    1    8    1    1    1     1     1     1     1
unnecessary.vs.necessary.    1    1    1    1    1    7    1    1    1     1     1     1     1
create.vs.destroy            1    1    1    1    1    8    1    1    1     1     1     1     4
```

I have created subsets for every category but that didn't help much. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[I want to make a graph like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBIFI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply want to add another column to your data, which holds the group information.

```
questionare <- data.frame(p1=sample(1:10,5),
                          p2=sample(1:10,5),
                          p3=sample(1:10,5),
                          p4=sample(1:10,5),
                          p5=sample(1:10,5),
                          row.names = paste0("q",1:5))


questionare$category <- c("A","A","B","B","C")
```

Like this, we can easily add a grouping to the questions. In order to reproduce the plot you can procede with something like this:

```
require(tidyverse)

questionare %>%  gather(variable,value,-category) %>% 
  mutate(cat_values = plyr::mapvalues(x=value,
                                      from = 1:10,
                                      to=c(rep("Disagree",3),
                                           rep("Neutral",4),
                                           rep("Agree",3)))) %>%
  group_by(category,cat_values) %>%  tally() %>%
  mutate(perc=n/sum(n)) -> questinaire_summarized


ggplot(questinaire_summarized,aes(x=perc,category,fill=cat_values))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys")+
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your answer. 
I tried adding a column like you suggested and in the environment I can see that a column has been added, but I cannot see it when I view it?

Also, what do I have to do in order to make a box plot like

boxplot(mean scores ~ category)

like how can I add a category I can actually work with and which I can see? :D 

thank you so much, really grateful already for the help :)

Comment: How do you view it? Using the head function? If you execute the variable you should see the new column. Regarding the visualization, I already showed how to use the category for creating a boxplot in my answer. However, if there are still open questions, please open a new question, or better look if there arent already similar questions available or other resources: e.g. http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/32-r-graphics-essentials/